# How to get all vertices in ArangoDB graph traversal without max?

Tags: arangodb

I want to get all vertices from graph，as shown below

```
a -> b -> c -> d -> e -> f -> ...
     b2 -> c2 -> cd -> ....
```

I want to get all vertices, and use syntax like:

```
[WITH vertexCollection1[, vertexCollection2[, ...vertexCollectionN]]]
FOR vertex[, edge[, path]]
  IN [min[..max]]
  OUTBOUND|INBOUND|ANY startVertex
  GRAPH graphName
  [PRUNE pruneCondition]
  [OPTIONS options]
```

as you can see, I have to define the value of max first( `IN [min[..max]]` ), how can I get all vertices without providing a value for max when the depth is unknown?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible, a `max` value must either be provided, or it will default to the `min` value (which in turn defaults to 1).

There's nothing to stop you from setting this to an arbitrarily large number though (e.g. `FOR v IN 1..99999999`) - you'll get all vertices as long as `max` exceeds your max depth.